# Finding the distribution of a minimum of a set of variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

I have been working on a problem where $X_1,...,X_n \sim \mathrm{Exp}(\beta)$ are
i.i.d.
and $Y = \min\left\{X_1^{0},X_2^{X_1},X_3^{X_1+X_2},...,X_n^{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i}\right\}$
. I want to find the PDF of $Y$, of which I am somewhat familiar with how
to generate, given that
$$P\left(Y \leq y\right) = P\left(\bigcup_{i \in [n]} X_i^{\sum_{j=1}^{i-1} X_j} \leq y\right),$$
But I seem to have an issue trying to apply the i.i.d. condition to make this
probability a sum, since the events by construction are dependent on each
other. Is there a reasonable mathematical method to solve a problem like this?
At the very least, is there a method where I can approximate this distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments:

You do not say whether $\beta$ is the mean or the rate.
Behavior seems to depend on whether the rate is greater
or less than 1.

I don't see how to simplify $Y$ analytically, but it seems easy to
simulate. As I understand the problem, here is a simulation of 100,000 iterations in R with $ n = 5$ and rate 6.

```
m = 10^5;  y = numeric(m);  n = 5;  lam = 6
for (i in 1:m) {
   x = rexp(n, lam);  cx = cumsum(c(0,x))[1:n]
   y[i] = min(x^cx) }
mean(y); sd(y)
## 0.2277121
## 0.1779304
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue")
```

[image]

... and another for rate = 1/6.

```
mean(y);  sd(y)
## 0.5591536
## 0.4767974
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the process $(Y_n)$ defined by $Y_{n+1}=\min\{Y_n,X_{n+1}^{S_n}\}$, with $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, Markov? The process $(Y,S)$ is obviously Markov, but $Y$ on its own?

Comment: Right. 'This' was not sufficiently specific. After sleeping on it, I'm not so sure the sentence 'hinting' about a possible analytic solution is helpful. Deleting it. Still hope the code may be helpful.